# mysql and aborted connections: why such a high number?

Tags: mysql

Good day,

I am a newbie with the mysql environment (I thank you in advance for your understanding and indulgence)... I have been looking at the statistics using the SHOW GLOBAL STATUS.

[image]

My server has been up for 24 hours only and I'm quite astonished to find such a high number of aborted clients. Could it be that I am missing a vital aspect in my programming of this method (which is called every 1/2 second in an AJAX) ?

```
function getLatestDataFromDatabase(){
    $query = 'CALL sp_tbl_domotique_components_get_values';
    if($result = $this->db->query($query)){
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
            $return .= $r -> tech_name . ' | ' . $r -> value_t_f . ' | ' . $r -> component_type . ' | ';
            $return .= '<hr/>';
            $data[] = $r;
        }

        $encode_donnees = json_encode($data);

    $myfile = fopen("output.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $encode_donnees);
    fclose($myfile);

    return $encode_donnees;
    }
}
```

Many thanks for your hints which are very appreciated.

Comment: What database connector are you using? Have you checked if db connector is always opening connections on query, but not closing them?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes for Aborted_clients as listed in

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/communication-errors.html

Attempted breakins are just one of the many possible causes.